# Check for consistent capitalization in word?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am trying to come up with some sort of macro to help me verify that I am consistently capitalizing words in my documents. I already use this macro to highlight the words that are capitalized, but it doesn't help me in verifying that all instances of that word are capitalized:

```
Sub Capitals()

Dim oRng As range
Set oRng = ActiveDocument.range
With oRng.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="([A-Z])", MatchWildcards:=True)
        oRng.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        oRng.Collapse 0
    Loop
End With

Dim oRng1 As range
Set oRng1 = ActiveDocument.range
With oRng1.Find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:="([.\!?]) [A-Z]*>", MatchWildcards:=True)
        oRng1.HighlightColorIndex = wdNoHighlight
        oRng1.Collapse 0
    Loop
End With
```

I am not even sure how to begin approaching this. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Your question isn't totally clear - I'm missing some example we could use for testing... But if you're already finding everything that's capitalized, why not add these words to an array, or write them to a file - whatever. Then loop through that list and use Find to search every instance of the terms, but NOT capitalized (using MatchCase) and replace with the capitalized version?

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this doesn't exactly seem quick. But, I think I would approach the problem with basically three steps:

1. Use regex to pull all words that are NOT the beginning of a
   sentence, and build a dictionary object of those words (with the
   word as the key and... anything as the value, more on this later).
   It would probably involve sub steps:

   - make a copy of your file
   - because VBA regex doesn't implement lookbehind, do a regex replace with all first words in a sentence (regex string would be something like this: "(([?!.] )|^)\w+'?\w*"), and replace with the null character
   - then use a regex (like "'?\b[\w']+\b'?") to match all words and put them in the dictionary
2. Make a sorted list from the collection. This might be easiest by pasting your collection into a range in excel. This has the
   advantage of then being able to do the rest through formulas and not
   any more VBA/code. I don't know of any in-built way to sort a
   dictionary object alphabetically by key in VBA... so you'd have to
   code one or find one.
3. Finally, now that you have the sorted list, go through and compare entries next to each other. If they are the same doing a
   case-insensitive compare, but different doing a case-sensitive
   compare, then add it to your final output.

Regarding the dictionary object: at first glance, the collection object seems better. But, I think the collection object in VBA is case-insensitive, with no way to make it case-sensitive. Dictionaries in VBA are case-sensitive by default (with a property that lets you set it to case-insensitive if you want).

Finally, I don't like my solution. But it's the only way I could think of to do it in VBA. Another option, not in VBA, would be to use something like Python with one of the ms office packages. This would let you use the negative lookbehind in your regex, and would also allow easier sorting of the list.

Comment: This solution works for me. Its enough for me to be able to know if there are a few missed words which I could than enter myself. I will probably try this in a couple of days when I get the chance. Thanks!